# Warum Endung "-es"

Tags: adjective-ending, declension

Ich habe gewusst, was *Beruhigend* bedeutet, aber ich weiß nicht warum dieses Wort *-es* am Ende hat? also Ich weiß, *-es* AKK ist und dekliniert. aber ich habe nicht *-es* Deklination gelesen. Können Sie mir erklären?

> Also ich ﬁnde, Fische haben so etwas Beruhigendes!